# GPU ResourceExhaustedError

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, gpu, vgg-net

I am training VGG16 network from scratch for a Binary Image Classification problem, but unfortunately, I face this error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[401408,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node gradients/dense_1/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1 (defined at /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_4981]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

As per a few suggestions on this error I googled, decreased the batch size from 64 to 16 but no luck.

My VM has 8GB ROM with 4 GPU's and the data size is less than 10MB. And GPU details as follows:

[image]

Comment: A batch size of `16` might still be too large, have you tried starting with batchsize `2` and increasing from there?

Comment: Nope. Let me give a try.

Comment: ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[401408,4096] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:RandomUniform]

Comment: Please include the model code, errors in isolation do not mean much.